# How to start a python operator boto3 AWS-glue task in airflow based on another AWS-glue task successful completion in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, aws-glue

My Ariflow script has several tasks using python operator to start a glue job using boto3. Even though the flow depends on each task in Ariflow. The consecutive tasks don't wait until the previous task's successful completion.

Next glue job task is called as soon as the previous glue job task is invoked. At the end even though the Airflow looks like successfully completed the glue jobs are still running for several minutes.

```
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from airflow.operators.sensors import TimeDeltaSensor
    import boto3
    import json

    default_args = {
    'owner': 'SAM',
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 5, 27)
     }


    glue_client = boto3.client('glue', region_name='us-east-1')

    def run_customer_job():
        glue_client.start_job_run(JobName='customer')  


    def run_product_job():
        glue_client.start_job_run(JobName='product')



    with DAG('dataload', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="0 15 * * *") as dag:
        task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='task1',                                              
                               python_callable=run_customer_job)
        task2 = PythonOperator(task_id='task2',                                                          
                               python_callable=run_product_job)



    task1 >> task2
```

Comment: Do you have a DAG code to share ?

Comment: Added the code to my question

Answer (score 1):

Create a new GlueOperator, based on https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/glue.py

Answer (score 0):

I would create a status loop after calling `start_job_run` so your task doesn't finish until the Glue job has.

Quick and simple example (you will need handling for failed tasks etc):

```py
job = glue_client.start_job_run(JobName='customer')

while True:
  status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=job['Name'], RunId=job['JobRunId'])
  if status['JobRun']['JobRunState'] == 'SUCCEEDED':
    break

  time.sleep(10)
```